# I want to scan through a txt file and save those numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

This is a small part of the program which I wrote to save contents of the file `BesselFunction.txt` into an array `ZeroBesselFuncTM`

```
constant=fopen("BesselFunction.txt","r");

for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    fscanf(constant,"%lf\n", &zero);
    ZeroBesselFuncTM[i]=zero;
    printf("inside for loop\n");
}

for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    printf("%0.4lf\n", ZeroBesselFuncTM[i]);
}
```

The array doesn't read my input file although it goes through the loop 19 times.

Comment: check return values of called function, `fscanf` should return the number of element scanned ( should be `1`, but couled be different if there was some error parsing the file content ).

Comment: The `'\n'` in the `fscanf` is not neccessary

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the file was opened and if input has been read. You also need to stop reading if the file ends prematurely.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "BesselFunction.txt";
    double ZeroBesselFuncTM[20];
    double zero;
    int i, j, n;
    FILE *constant;

    constant = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (constant != NULL) {
        i = -1;
        do {
            i++;
            n = fscanf(constant, "%lf\n", &zero);
            if (n == 1) {
                ZeroBesselFuncTM[i] = zero;
            } else if (n == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
            }
        } while ((i < 20) && (n != EOF));
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%0.4f\n", ZeroBesselFuncTM[j]);
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** Check the error whether file opened correctly or not.

```
constant=fopen("BesselFunction.txt","r");
if(constant == NULL) {
  //Process the error
}
```

Also check the file `BesselFunction.txt` present in the same directory where the executable runs.

**Second** Check the `fscanf` error code for more update.

```
int result = fscanf(constant,"%lf\n", &zero);

 if (result <= 0) {
 //Process the error.
 }
```

Comment: `result` should be `<1` if there is an error (most likely `0` ).

Comment: testing `result!=1` should be sufficient